# How to detect a non-rolling log file and pattern match in a shell script which is using tail, while, read, and?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, while-loop, scripting

I am monitoring a log file and if `PATTERN` didn't appear in it within `THRESHOLD` seconds, the script should print "error", otherwise, it should print "clear". The script is working fine, but only if the log is rolling.

I've tried reading 'timeout' but didn't work.

```
log_file=/tmp/app.log
threshold=120

tail -Fn0 ${log_file} | \
while read line ; do
  echo "${line}" | awk '/PATTERN/ { system("touch pattern.tmp") }'
```

code to calculate how long ago pattern.tmp touched and same is assigned to `DIFF`

```
if [ ${diff} -gt ${threshold} ]; then
   echo "Error"
else
   echo "Clear"
done
```

It is working as expected only when there is 'any' line printed in the app.log.

If the application got hung for any reason and the log stopped rolling, there won't be any output by the script.

Is there a way to detect the 'no output' of `tail` and do some command at that time?

Comment: Dear vijesh, welcome to Stack Overflow. You mention your script is running fine if your log is rolling. This might be true if your logfile is growing at a constant pace. If your log file gets only now-and-then new lines, the buffer connected to the pipe will break the purpose of your script. It might be wiser to use `stdbuf -oL tail -Fn0 ${LOG FILE}`

Comment: @kvantour Thanks so much. Even though the log file is rapidly growing one, stdbuf  might help in testing or QA environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem you're having is that the timing calculations inside your `while` loop never get a chance to run when `read` is blocking on input. In that case, you can pipe the `tail` output into a `while true` loop, inside of which you can do `if read -t $timeout`:

```
log_file=/tmp/app.log
threshold=120
timeout=10

tail -Fn0 "$log_file" | while true; do
  if read -t $timeout line; then
    echo "${line}" | awk '/PATTERN/ { system("touch pattern.tmp") }'
  fi

  # code to calculate how long ago pattern.tmp touched and same is assigned to diff 

  if [ ${diff} -gt ${threshold} ]; then
    echo "Error"
  else
    echo "Clear"
  fi
done
```

As Ed Morton pointed out, all caps variable names are not a good idea in bash scripts, so I used lowercase variable names.

Comment: The read 'timeout' worked when it  was inside the while true loop! Thanks so much Mike. I've made a few changes and the code now look like this:

Comment: log_file=/tmp/app.log
threshold=30
timeout=60

stdbuf -oL tail -Fn0 ${log_file} | while true; do
  if read -t $timeout line; then
    echo "${line}" | awk '/PATTERN/ { system("touch pattern.tmp") }'
    p_time=$(date +%s)
    f_time=$(stat pattern.tmp -c %Y)
    diff=$(expr ${p_time} - ${f_time})
    if [ ${diff} -gt ${threshold} ]; then
      echo "PATTERN not found"
    else
      echo "PATTERN found" 
    fi
  else
    echo "log is not rolling" 
  fi
done

Answer (score 0):

How about something simple like:

```
sleep "$threshold"
grep -q 'PATTERN' "$log_file" && { echo "Clear"; exit; }
echo "Error"
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to clarify your requirements. Don't use all upper case for non exported shell variable names btw - google it.

Comment: I think OP wants to continually check for *new* matches of `PATTERN`. This would just print "Clear" every time after the first instance of `PATTERN` appears in the log.

Comment: @MikeHolt I know that's what the OPs code does but what my code does is all he needs to implement what he's told us so far about his problem so I'm trying to get him to expand on the requirements in his question if he actually needs a solution to do more than just `monitoring a log file and if PATTERN didn't appear in it within THRESHOLD seconds, the script should print "error", otherwise, it should print "clear"`.

Comment: Thank you MikeHolt and Ed Morton. I've changed vars to lower case. My issue seems to be with the while loop as pointed out by Mike Holt!

Answer (score 0):

To build further on your idea, it might be beneficial to run the awk part in the background and a continuous loop to do the checking.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

log_file="log.txt"
# threshold in seconds
threshold=10

# run the following process in the background
stdbuf -oL tail -f0n "$log_file" \
   | awk '/PATTERN/{system("touch "pattern.tmp") }' &

while true; do
    match=$(find . -type f  -iname "pattern.tmp" -newermt "-${threshold} seconds")
    if [[ -z "${match}" ]]; then
        echo "Error"
    else
        echo "Clear"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you kvantour. I will have to try this one too.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like a watchdog timer. I've implemented something like this by forcing a background process to update my log, so I don't have to worry about `read -t`. Here's a working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

threshold=10
grain=2

errorstate=0

while sleep "$grain"; do
        date '+[%F %T] watchdog timer' >> log
done &
trap "kill -HUP $!" 0 HUP INT QUIT TRAP ABRT TERM

printf -v lastseen '%(%s)T'
tail -F log | while read line; do
        printf -v now '%(%s)T'
        if (( now - lastseen > threshold )); then
                echo "ERROR"
                errorstate=1
        else
                if (( errorstate )); then
                        echo "Recovered, yay"
                        errorstate=0
                fi
        fi
        if [[ $line =~ .*PATTERN.* ]]; then
                lastseen=$now
        fi
done
```

Run this in one window, wait `$threshold` seconds for it to trigger, then in another window `echo PATTERN >> log` to see the recovery.

While this can be made as granular as you like (I've set it to 2 seconds in the example), it does pollute your log file.

Oh, and note that `printf '%(%s)T'` format requires bash version 4 or above.

Comment: Thank you ghoti, I will have to try this once I get a chance.